# If $\pi$ is not algebraic number then : is $\pi ^{n}$ algebraic number for $n >1$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers

if  $\pi$ is not algebraic number then : is $$\pi ^{n}$$ 
 algebraic number for $n >1$ ?

Thank you for any kind of help .

Comment: The $n$'th root of an algebraic number is algebraic.

Comment: but pi is not algebraic

Comment: And that answers the question.

Comment: Exactly. Thus $\pi^n$ is not algebraic. It is the contrapositive form of that statement

Comment: Just a curiosity: What do you mean by $\pi^{2}=10$?

Comment: Further to Tobias, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial, and $p(y) =0$ then, notice that $p(x^n)$ is also a polynomial and it has $\sqrt[n]{y}$ as a root.

Comment: p²=10 and 10 is algebraic number ?? ,

Comment: The fact that $\pi^2 \approx 10$ tells us nothing about whether $\pi^2$ is algebraic or not.

Comment: When you say "I would like to take: $\pi^2=10$", you are redefining what the symbol $\pi$ means. At that point it no longer has anything to do with the circle dimension ratio that you appeared to be talking about earlier. Note that any neighbourhood of a rational number contains an infinite number of irrationals, and vice versa, so numerical proximity means nothing to this argument.

Comment: This question is very poorly written, unless you say explicitly that n is an integer or a rational number there are obviously numbers such that π^n is algebraic, for example 2ln(2) /ln(π)

Answer (score 9):

Assume that $\pi^n$ is algebraic, with minimal polynomial $p(x)$.

Then $\pi$ is a root of $p(x^n)$, hence $\pi$ is algebraic, contradiction.

Comment: if we take p²=10 then p²  is algebraic*

Comment: if we take pi² =10 then it 's algebraic number with minimal polynomial p(x)

Comment: How do you "take $\pi^2 = 10$"?

Comment: approximation of pi² , it's used in many area

Comment: @Zeraouliarafik You don't write $=$ when it is an approximation. And you don't do approximations when dealing with algebraic numbers

Comment: I can't to add now what i meant since the question is answered

Comment: @Zeraouliarafik: a single approximation does not tell anything about a number being algebraic or not. For instance $\pi$ is very close to $\frac{355}{113}$, but $\pi$ is not algebraic.